# Generics, arrays, and the ClassCastException

Tags: java, arrays, generics, classcastexception

I think there must be something subtle going on here that I don't know about. Consider the following:

```
public class Foo<T> {
  private T[] a = (T[]) new Object[5];

  public Foo() {
    // Add some elements to a
  }

  public T[] getA() {
    return a;
  }
}
```

Suppose that your main method contains the following:

```
Foo<Double> f = new Foo<Double>();
Double[] d = f.getA();
```

You will get a `CastClassException` with the message `java.lang.Object` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Double`.

Can anyone tell me why? My understanding of `ClassCastException` is that it is thrown when you try to cast an object to a type that cannot be casted. That is, to a subclass of which it is not an instance (to quote the documentation). e.g.:

```
Object o = new Double(3.);
Double d = (Double) o; // Working cast
String s = (String) o; // ClassCastException
```

And it seems I can do this. If `a` was just a `T` instead of an array `T[]`, we can get `a` and cast it without a problem. Why do arrays break this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming this is all because you can't create generic arrays. Have you considered using an ArrayList<T> instead?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Foo<Double> f = new Foo<Double>();
```

When you use this version of the generic class Foo, then for the member variable `a`, the compiler is essentially taking this line:

```
private T[] a = (T[]) new Object[5];
```

and replacing `T` with `Double` to get this:

```
private Double[] a = (Double[]) new Object[5];
```

You cannot cast from Object to Double, hence the ClassCastException.

**Update and Clarification:** Actually, after running some test code, the ClassCastException is more subtle than this. For example, this main method will work fine without any exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo<Double> f = new Foo<Double>();
    System.out.println(f.getA());
}
```

The problem occurs when you attempt to assign `f.getA()` to a reference of type `Double[]`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo<Double> f = new Foo<Double>();
    Double[] a2 = f.getA(); // throws ClassCastException
    System.out.println(a2);
}
```

This is because the type-information about the member variable `a` is erased at runtime. Generics only provide type-safety at *compile-time* (I was somehow ignoring this in my initial post). So the problem is not

```
private T[] a = (T[]) new Object[5];
```

because at run-time this code is really

```
private Object[] a = new Object[5];
```

The problem occurs when the result of method `getA()`, which at runtime actually returns an `Object[]`, is assigned to a reference of type `Double[]` - this statement throws the ClassCastException because Object cannot be cast to Double.

**Update 2**: to answer your final question "why do arrays break this?" The answer is because the language specification does not support generic array creation. [See this forum post for more](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=530823) - in order to be backwards compatible, nothing is known about the type of T at runtime.

Comment: you are right i figured after reading the link i posted in my answer :)

Comment: for all those wanting to read it too: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20type%20parameter?

Comment: The above link has some good info in it - might help the original question-asker understand more about type-erasure and what is known at run-time vs compile-time

Comment: -1 because the explanation is unclear and cluttered. Pandya's one is better.

Comment: Java compiler erase generic by "Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded" (ref:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so you said "replacing T with Double" is not correct, it should replacing T with Object actually @matt b

Answer (score 6):

There may be some small errors in @mattb's explanation.

The error is *not*

> java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Double.

It is:

> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double

The [L means an array. That is, the error is that an *array* of Objects cannot be cast to an array of Double. This is the same case as following:

```
Object[] oarr = new Object[10];
Double[] darr = (Double[]) oarr;
```

This is obviously not allowed.

For your issue of creating typesafe arrays, another alternative is to except a class object in init and use Array.newInstance:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

class Foo<T> {
  private T[] a ;

  public Foo(Class<T> tclass) {
    a = (T[]) Array.newInstance(tclass, 5);
  }

  public T[] getA() {
    return a;
  }

  public static <T> Foo<T> create(Class<T> tclass) {
    return new Foo<T>(tclass);
  }
}

class Array1
{
  public static final void main(final String[] args) {
    Foo<Double> f = Foo.create(Double.class);
    Double[] d = f.getA();
  }


}
```

Comment: Is there ever a case where you can cast from type A to B but not A[] to B[]?

Comment: You can *never* cast from A[] to B[]. Consider two classes Fruit and Apple (extends Fruit). So you can cast from Apple to Fruit. But you cannot cast from Apple[] to Fruit[]. Because you can add /any/ Fruit (say Orange) to Fruit[], but only Apple to Apple[]

Comment: Oh wait, don't know what I was talking about. For two classes C1 < C2 (that is C2 can be assigned to C1), and a generic class G, C1[] < C2[] but ! G<C1> < G<C2>. 

That is, Apple[] can be assigned to Fruit[] but List<Apple> cannot be assigned to List<Fruit>....[contd]

Comment: But when you (try to) store an Orange in a Fruit[] whose dynamic type is Apple[] you get an ArrayStoreException.

Answer (score 3):

@matt b: Thanks for the answer! Very helpful.

I have found a workaround for those interested: give the getA method an initialized array to populate. That way the type info is available.

```
public class Foo<T> {
  private T[] a = (T[]) new Object[5];

  public Foo() {
    // Add some elements to a
  }

  public T[] getA(T[] holdA) {
    // Check whether holdA is null and handle it...then:
    holdA = (T[]) Array.newInstance(holdA.getClass().getComponentType(), a.length);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, holdA, 0, a.length);
    return holdA;
  }
}
```

Then for your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Foo<Double> f = new Foo<Double>();
  Double[] a2 = new Double[1];
  a2 = f.getA(a2);
}
```