# Array return can be used in assignment, but not in loop

Tags: java, arrays, class, generics

I was posting an answer to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987782/returning-an-array-from-a-generic-class-how-do-i-print-the-data-from-the-array/27988439#27988439), when I came across a little mystery.  The class definition (slightly modified from the original questioner) is here:

```
public class Playground<T>{
    private int pos;
    private final int size;
    private T[] arrayOfItems;
    public Playground(int size){
        this.size = size;
        pos = 0;
        arrayOfItems = (T[]) new Object[size];
    }

    public void addItem(T item) {
        arrayOfItems[pos] = item;
        pos++;
    }

    public void displayItems() {
        for(int i = 0;i<pos;i++){
            System.out.println(arrayOfItems[i]);
        }
    }

    public T[] returnItems() { 
        return (T[]) arrayOfItems;
    }
}
```

In main, we then create a new Playground, `Playground<String> animals = new Playground<String>(5);` and put some animal Strings in it.  (Dog, Cat, etc).

The mystery is that this works:

```
Object[] s = animals.returnItems();
for(int i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(s[i]);
}
```

But this creates a `ClassCastException` *in the for loop declaration*.

```
for(int i=0; i < animals.returnItems().length; i++) {
        System.out.println(animals.returnItems()[i]);
}
```

Both `Object[]`s and `String[]`s have length variables.  Why does using the accessor method in the loop declaration cause an exception?

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: @jervine10 I confess that I don't really know how to do that (or get anything meaningful out of it.)  I still have lots of things to learn :)

Comment: The whole array casting seems weird. `Object[]` is not instance of `String[]` so actually it should throw `ClassCastException` right in the constructor. To know what is going on you would probably need to check bytecode.

Comment: you can edit your question

Comment: @Pavel - if you try to put it into a String[] (or even cast to a String[]), it will give you a ClassCastException.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment... due to type erasure the actual property type would be `Object[]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics, arrays, and the ClassCastException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372250/generics-arrays-and-the-classcastexception)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that there is a `ClassCastException` -- cannot cast from `Object[]` to `String[]` -- is because of what the compiler does when using generics.  When calling `returnItems()`, the compiler inserts a cast to `String[]`, because `returnItems` returns `T[]`.  Type erasure upon compilation means that it's returning an `Object[]`, but since `T` is `String` here, the compiler inserts a cast to `String[]`.  But the original object `arrayOfItems` isn't a `String[]`, it's an `Object[]`, so the cast fails.

This should have resulted in an "unchecked cast" warning during compilation, from `Object[]` to `T[]`.

What you will need to do instead is to follow the advice here in [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) in creating a generic array.

Accept a `Class<T>` in your constructor, so you can call `Array.newInstance` and get a `T[]` from the start.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  // This suppression is safe.
public Playground(int size, Class<T> clazz){
    this.size = size;
    pos = 0;
    arrayOfItems = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
}
```

Then you can create `animals` by passing `String.class`:

```
Playground<String> animals = new Playground<String>(5, String.class);
```

**Update**

The following is a reasonable explanation as to why the first example works (assigning to an `Object[]`) when the second example doesn't work (accessing the field `length` directly on the return type of the `returnItems()` method.

**First example**

```
Object[] s = animals.returnItems();
for(int i=0; i < s.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(s[i]);
}
```

The [JLS, Section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), describes "Assignment Contexts" which govern what happens when assigning a value from an expression to a variable.

> The only exceptions that may arise from conversions in an assignment context are:
>
> - A ClassCastException if, after the conversions above have been applied, the resulting value is an object which is not an instance of a subclass or subinterface of the erasure (§4.6) of the type of the variable.
>
> This circumstance can only arise as a result of heap pollution (§4.12.2). In practice, implementations need only perform casts when accessing a field or method of an object of parameterized type when the erased type of the field, or the erased return type of the method, differ from its unerased type.
>
> ...

The compiler did not need to insert a cast to `String[]` here.  When the `length` field is accessed later, the variable is already of type `Object[]`, so there is no problem here.

**Second example**

```
for(int i=0; i < animals.returnItems().length;i++) {
    System.out.println(animals.returnItems()[i]);
}
```

The `ClassCastException` here appears not to be dependent on the `for` loop; this error will occur with a simple print of the length:

```
System.out.println(animals.returnItems().length);
```

This is a *field access expression*, covered by the [JLS, Section 15.11.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1).

> [T]he identifier names a single accessible member field in type T, and the type of the field access expression is the type of the member field after capture conversion (§5.1.10).

Capture conversion captures the type as `String[]`.  The compiler must insert the cast to `String[]` here for the same reason as it would insert the cast for a method call - the field or method may only exist on the captured type.

Because the type of `arrayOfItems` is really `Object[]`, the cast fails.

As described above, creating the generic array with `Array.newInstance` solves this issue, because an actual `String[]` is being created.  With that change, the inserted cast is still present, but this time it succeeds.

Comment: It appears that the compiler doesn't need to insert a cast when the target type  of the assignment is `Object[]`.

Comment: I have added a more thorough explanation as to why the compiler doesn't need to insert the cast on the first example, and why it does need to insert the cast on the second example.